# Is there a way to interpolate scalar values for the interior from a closed surface in VTK?

Tags: vtk

I have a closed VTK surface with scalar values on the surface.
I plan to create a volumetric mesh from the surface.

Is there a way to interpolate the scalar values for the interior of the surface?

Anything available in VTK or alternatively, any pointers regarding useful algorithms would be appreciated.

I've found algorithms for the reverse problem, i.e interpolating the scalar values for a surface, but haven't been successful in finding any descriptions to solutions for my problem.

Any help would be appreciated. Please feel free to direct me to the appropriate place to ask the question if needed.

Comment: Interpolating scalar value distribution inside of your closed surface is an ill-posed problem because so many different bulk (i.e. volumetric space inside of your closed surface) distribution of that scalar value could lead to the already known surface scalar distribution. Is there any additional constraint on the bulk scalar distribution rather than just satisfying that already known boundary condition (i.e. known surface scalar distribution)? If the answer is yes, please elaborate it in the main question. But, if the answer is no, I would elaborate it in the next comment...

Comment: If the answer is no, a simple way, but not really the best way or the only way, to find a bulk scalar distribution based on your known boundary condition is to solve a simple Laplace equation ($\nabla \phi = 0$), where $\phi$ is your scalar variable by using the boundary condition of: $\phi = \phi_{0} \forall \vec{r} \in \partial \Omega$, where $\partial \Omega$ is your already known closed boundary and $\phi_{0}$ is the already known scalar value at that boundary. It needs some sort of finite element or finite difference code but it should be doable...